# Moving Quantity after product description

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, filters

Using woo-commerce I need to place the quantity after the description. Below attached screenshot shows expected output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to make it done is by playing with hook priorities.

On `content-single-product.php` is this comment:

```
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
     */
```

So to put something after excerpt, it needs to have the priority between 20 - 30. First of all you need to remove `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` which shows the quantity and add to cart button.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
```

Then register this same action but with higher priority which shows the quantity and add to cart button after excerpt.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary',woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 20);
```

Since you want to move just the quantity, my solution would be to register the action again .. the priority is up to you.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
```

and with simple css hide the button after the excerpt and below hide the quantity.